# Just installed PhpStorm 2021.3.2 crashes on startup

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've fully deleted PhpStorm 2019, all plugins and cache, downloaded and installed PhpStorm 2021.3.2 and it crashes on startup. Reinstallation with cleaning-up doesn't help.

**idea.log (I had to cut out some of the logs because StackOverflow wouldn't let me publish the question)**

```
2022-02-15 20:59:56,892 [  263] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@9a2e852[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 6, active = 3, running = 3, steals = 3, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@bd6cba9 
2022-02-15 20:59:57,533 [  904] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 641 ms 
2022-02-15 20:59:57,772 [ 1143] INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2022-02-15 20:59:58,137 [ 1508] INFO - .intellij.util.io.HttpRequests - Application is not initialized yet; Using default SSL configuration to connect to https://www.jetbrains.com/config/IdeaCloudConfig.xml 
2022-02-15 20:59:58,818 [ 2189] INFO - nfig.ETagCloudConfigFileClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files === 
2022-02-15 20:59:59,331 [ 2702]  ERROR - Config.CloudConfigProviderImpl - Invalid credentials 
com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.exception.UnauthorizedException: Invalid credentials
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.AbstractHttpClient.download(AbstractHttpClient.java:95)
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.CloudConfigFileClient.list(CloudConfigFileClient.java:192)
    at com.intellij.idea.cloudConfig.ETagCloudConfigFileClient.list(ETagCloudConfigFileClient.java:36)
    at com.intellij.idea.cloudConfig.CloudConfigProviderImpl.<init>(CloudConfigProviderImpl.java:46)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.beforeImportConfigs(MainImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.importConfig(StartupUtil.java:404)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$16(StartupUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1072)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files/PhpStorm/
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.jetbrains.cloudconfig.AbstractHttpClient.download(AbstractHttpClient.java:92)
    ... 15 more
2022-02-15 20:59:59,336 [ 2707]  ERROR - Config.CloudConfigProviderImpl - PhpStorm 2021.3.2  Build #PS-213.6777.58 
2022-02-15 20:59:59,340 [ 2711]  ERROR - Config.CloudConfigProviderImpl - JDK: 11.0.13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-02-15 20:59:59,340 [ 2711]  ERROR - Config.CloudConfigProviderImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2022-02-15 20:59:59,345 [ 2716] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - Importing configs to C:\Users\Semyon\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.3 
2022-02-15 20:59:59,364 [ 2735] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - Importing configs: oldConfigDir=[C:\Users\Semyon\.PhpStorm2021.3.2\config], newConfigDir=[C:\Users\Semyon\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.3], oldIdeHome=[null], oldPluginsDir=[C:\Users\Semyon\.PhpStorm2021.3.2\config\plugins], newPluginsDir=[C:\Users\Semyon\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.3\plugins] 
2022-02-15 21:00:00,178 [ 3549] INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=PHP, id=com.jetbrains.php, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2021.3.2\plugins\php, version=213.6777.58, package=null, isBundled=true) misses optional descriptor php-shared-indexes.xml 
2022-02-15 21:00:00,964 [ 4335] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - Migrating plugin io.pmmp.phpstorm.stub version 3.11.5 
2022-02-15 21:00:00,996 [ 4367] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - The vmoptions file has changed, restarting... 
2022-02-15 21:00:01,013 [ 4384] INFO - #com.intellij.util.Restarter - run restarter: [C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2021.3.2\bin\restarter.exe, 14340, 1, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2021.3.2\bin\phpstorm64.exe] 
2022-02-15 21:00:01,589 [ 4960] INFO - #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2022-02-15 21:00:01,594 [ 4965] INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

Comment: With these kind of question you better contact JetBrains Support directly -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm and click on big blue "Submit a request" button at the top: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 There you can privately attach your logs, screenshot and any other relevant/requested info.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your appdata? this can be found here: C:\Users\Semyon\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains

Comment: Anyway: what folders have you deleted/clean up? What PhpStorm/JetBrains folders do you have left? *"oldConfigDir=[C:\Users\Semyon\.PhpStorm2021.3.2\config]"* -- this is unexpected. **Since 2020.1** the IDE uses `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.3` kind of path -- it no longer uses user root folder for that for quite some time. So it's very unexpected to see such `~\.PhpStorm2021.3.2\config` path there. My only guess so far -- you may have copied it there manually...

Comment: Here are what folders/paths the IDE uses: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Just tried to uninstall PhpStorm and clear Roaming and Local, then install PhpStorm again. Doesn't work.

Comment: I uninstalled PhpStorm, deleted folders in Roaming, Local and user root directory, then installed again and it helped. Thank you!